# U-SQL procedure call order

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

Let we have script that consists of 3 procedure calls:

```
mydb.myschema.PopulateDimensions(...)
mydb.myschema.PopulateFactTable(...)
mydb.myschema.UpdateStatistics(...)
```

Will they be executed in the same order or they will be inlined into the script and the entire mix will be executed in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will be inlined and then the compiler, optimizer and scheduler will determine how to best execute the overall script.

What are you trying to achieve/hope for?

Comment: I need schedule execution of these procedures in the order above. And i thought about 2 cases: a) put these calls into a one script and schedule it in an ADF; b) schedule every proc individually in an ADF to force predictable order. Looks like i should choose (b). Thank you as always.